# Form answer Spreadsheet - onChange trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

I would like to ask about running **onChange trigger after change is made in spreadsheet by Google Form**.

I have this source code for sending email after change is made:

```
function onChange(e){

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var helpRange = sheet.getRange(2, 16);
    var debugRange = sheet.getRange(2,17);
    var startRow = helpRange.getValue();
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1;   // Number of rows to process
    debugRange.setValue(numRows);
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var title = row[3];
      var desc = "Description: " + row[4] + " Requested Accounts: " + row[5] + " Marketing Support: " + row[6] + " Responsible Salesman " + row[8] + " Email: " + row[9] + " " + row[10];      // Second column
      var tstart = row[1];
      var tstop = row[2];
      var loc = row[7];

      cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tstart), new Date(tstop), {description:desc,location:loc});


      helpRange.setValue(sheet.getLastRow() + 1);
      var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 10).getValue(); 
      var subject = "New Event Created: " + title;
      Browser.msgBox(emailAddress + " " + subject + " "+ desc);
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, desc); 

    }
}
```

**This spreadsheet should be automatically filled by Google Form** (when user submit an answer) and no other user should do any change to it. This onChange trigger is fired every time I made some change physically (as expected but this wouldn't happen) but when I submit answer from Google Form, it is displayed also in spreadsheet but onChange trigger isn't fired.

Why?

Can I write it so that trigger will be fired after change is made by Google Form?

Comment: You want the "Form Submit" trigger. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events

Comment: Also, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); will only work if a spreadsheet is open, maybe better to open by ID

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 major points to understand why it's not working:

1. Like ryan-roth said, the method to use in this case is `onFormSubmit()`.
2. This method in particular has to be used in a [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), so you must create it through the Apps Script Dashboard or programmatically using the [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script) service, wich I recommend because it's more simple to understand what's going on. The following code is an example of a function to create a trigger for this case:

```
function createTriggerFunction(){
  //Get the target spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
  //Create a new trigger using ScriptApp service passing your function as parameter
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("yourMailFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create()
  
}
```

3. Now, for this new trigger to install, in your Google App Script Editor you have to select this `createTriggerFunction()` in the *Select Function* list and Run it once, otherwise you're creating the same trigger for each time you run it.
   [image]
4. This point is important for this to work: Overwritting functions is for **Simple** Triggers, in wich case onChange() and onFormSubmit() [**are not**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). So in this case your code will work using it in a new function called `yourMailFunction` for the sake of this example.

```
function yourMailFunction(e){

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXX');

    ...

    }
}
```

### IMPORTANT

Note that i've used `SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXX')` instead `SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSheet()`. This is **very important** because when the Form submits and inserts a new row in the associated spreadsheet, **there is no active spreadsheet** so you have to call it by it's ID.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by eddyparkinson, you definitely want a form submit trigger, not a change or edit trigger.

It is possible to set up a [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers) in either the Google Form, or in the Google Sheet that receives the form's responses. The trigger event in each case is slightly different; the [Google Sheets form submit event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) contains the form entry values in simple arrays (e.values, e.namedValues), whereas the [Forms form submit event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) contains a [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) object that can be queried for all the information about the form submission.